# LPL Predicate Logic Translations Exercise 11.20.7

Tags: logic, translation

I have this one question (Part 7) in exercise 11.20 that I can't seem to get the answer from.

[image]

I tried ∀x∀y ((x ≠ y ∧ Larger(x,y)) → Dodec(x)) and ∀x∀y (Larger(x,y) → Dodec(x)), as well as many other things so far, and none of them have passed through GradeGrinder.

Thanks!

Comment: 12 ? Too many. Try with the first couple of the,. What have you tried about 1 and 2 ?

Comment: And the two transaltions you have written above refer to what ?

Comment: Sorry I'm just referring to part 7 of this question :Only dodecahedra are larger than everything else. I'm fine with the other parts.

Comment: "There is no **x** such that for every **y**, if not **x=y**, then **Larger(x,y)** and not **Dodec(x)**."

Comment: That didn't work either

Comment: You can find an equivalent translation moving inside the negation sign.

Answer (score 1):

> I tried ∀x∀y ((x ≠ y ∧ Larger(x,y)) → Dodec(x)) and ∀x∀y (Larger(x,y) → Dodec(x)),

Translate it a bit at a time.

- "Only dodecahdera are larger than everything else."
- ∀x ("larger than everything else"(x) → Dodec(x))
- ∀x (∀y (x ≠ y → Larger(x,y)) → Dodec(x))

If you need it in prenex form, use contraposition and duality, so you may apply null quantification.

- ∀x (~Dodec(x)→~∀y (x ≠ y → Larger(x,y)))
- ∀x (~Dodec(x)→Ǝy (x ≠ y & ~Larger(x,y)))
- ∀x Ǝy (~Dodec(x)→(x ≠ y & ~Larger(x,y)))

Check the translation:

- "If anything is not a dodecahedra, there is something else that it is not larger than."
- ?= "Only dodecahedra are larger than everything else."